# Not able to merge DWR with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dwr

Using spring 4.2.0, Dwr 3.
Using annotations to create all spring controllers, service and daos. Working fine till it's in spring only environment. Trying to add DWR as seperate spring controller service object is not injecting into that DWR controller. Getting below error with NullPointerException

```
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Below is the code snippet.
Dwr Controller is

```
@Controller
@RemoteProxy(name = "dwrDemo")
public class DwrDemoController {
@Autowired
private BrandNameService brandNameService;


public void setBrandNameService(BrandNameService brandNameService) {
    this.brandNameService = brandNameService;
}


@RemoteMethod
public List<String> getEmployeeDetails(int id) {
   return brandNameService.getEmployeeDetails(id);
}
:
}
```

Service class is like

```
@Service("brandNameService")
@Transactional
public class BrandNameServiceImpl implements BrandNameService{
  public List<String> getEmployeeDetails(int id) {
     return brandNameDAO.getEmployeeDetails(id);
  }
:
}
```

If I define the DWR controller in xml and removing all annotations in DWR Controller, server it getting up without initializing service object (here while calling dwr getting NullPointerException)
Below is XML

```
<beans:bean id="dwrDemoController"
    class="com.classified.dwr.controller.DwrDemoController">
    <!-- <beans:property name="brandNameService" ref="brandNameService"/> -->
    <dwr:remote javascript="dwrService">
        <dwr:include method="getEmployeeDetails" />
    </dwr:remote>
</beans:bean>
```

If I uncomment brandNameService, tomcat is not getting up, getting above exception/error while up

Comment: Start by using constructor injection instead, and see if that identifies the issue. I suspect that DWR is not cooperating properly with the Spring container.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked when I defined all the beans in applicationContext.xml instead of myapp-servlet.xml.